LSI Megaraid UI on multihomed (mult. IPs) Windows 10 picks wrong IP
The LSI Megaraid Storage Manager runs as a client on a Windows 10 computer. It is supposed to access a server remotely. However, the client does not receive any updates from the server (log, events, etc.), although the interaction basically works.
The problem is that the Windows 10 computer has acquired a large number of interfaces and IP addresses over time (virtual machines, OpenVPN interfaces, mobile interface, hyper-v, sandbox, etc.). When the MSM is started (via javaw), it takes an IP address from one of the interfaces that are currently without meaning or function; very often from one of the 172.x.y.z networks of the virtual Ethernet Switch (vEthernet).
Although I can enter the IP address of the server in the MSM client UI at startup (discover), the server cannot send any updates to the client (log, events) after connect, because the client probably grabs a source IP address that does not originate from the WLAN/LAN (where the server is located) and the server cannot send packets or the client cannot receive them. It always shows me one of the 172.x.y.z addresses in the IP address field at startup, which is wrong. The client can then interact with the server remotely, but it does not receive any events or log updates from the server.
It works if I deactivate all other interfaces (this could also be done by deinstalling hyper-v, sandbox and others). Ports 3071 and 5571 are not blocked. So I should somehow be able to tell the MSM which IP address is the primary one for it to start with and to receive messages from the server. But I have no idea how to do this.
To make it simple, MSM seems to bind to the wrong local IP / interface.
Any ideas? Any tips?
Thanks!

netstat could be your friend. mega raid usually have config files and the port is known, so we can fix is issue by editing usually. but my last MRM fixis too far away to get it correctly out of my brain again
